# Exponential distribution between two numbers

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, exponential-distribution

I must calculate the probability : $P(43 < X < 63)$

How do we even calculate the probability between two numbers ? I have a formula for the situation when : $P(X > a)= e^{‐λa}$. Must I use the density function in this situation ?

By the way, $λ =\dfrac{1}{25}$.

My guess is that I'll have to do some substraction of areas but I'm not sure ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cdf is $F_X(x)$, then $$\Pr(X\le b)=F_X(b)$$
and
$$\Pr(a<X\le b)=F_X(b)-F_X(a)$$

The exponential cdf is $F_X(x)=1 − e^{-\lambda x}$.
You can substitute the $\le$ with $<$, since the cdf is continuous.

Comment: What does cdf mean ? Btw, i tried the technique you told me but for some reason it didnt work before you posted your answer. Maybe i did na error of computatioN ? Ill go try again !

Comment: [Cumulative Distribution Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) is the integral of the [pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function).

Comment: Is it normale I'm having a negative asnwer ? Im supposed to calculate it between 25 and 45. I substract e^(-45/25) - e^(-25/25) = -0.2025805529498558

Comment: No it is wrong. Probability is positive. Just use the cdf in my answer with $b=63$ and $a=43$ (or any other $b$ and $a$, where $b>a$)

Comment: Oh ok, I got the exact the same answer as I have posted but it is positive now. Weird.

Comment: if the pdf is continuous and theere is no $\delta$ at that specific point (which is often the case), then the probability of that point is zero.